# Add class member vs many instances

Tags: c#

In my program, I have to add new instance of a given class to an ArrayList each time a method is invoked. My code looks like.

```
public class A
{
    List<Object> myList = new List<Object>();
    void resetMyList()
    {
        myList.Clear();
        myList.Add(new B());
        // Add more strings
        // Call other methods
        // ...
        // Get a list of strings
    }
}

public class B
{
    public override string toString()
    {
         return "I'm B";
    }
}
```

One of my colleague suggested to add new property to class A that refers to one instance of class B. So class B will only be created once and stay in the memory. With this solution, we can avoid to make the garbage collector works on creating and deleting new instance of B. Here is his code:

```
public class A
{
    List<Object> myList = new List<Object>();
    private B b = new B();
    void resetMyList()
    {
        myList.Clear();
        myList.Add(b);
        // Add more strings
        // Call other methods
        // ...
        // Get a list of strings
    }
}
```

So which suggestion is better, design and performance wise?

Edit: Please I know that using:

- Using List is better than using ArrayList
- Codes are not equivalent

I just want to keep the example simple and my concern is about design and memory. Whether to add private member and keep it in memory or create new instance each time and avoid extra members.
Any way I will change the code to use List

Comment: [codereview.se]

Comment: @UnholySheep it's c# code according to method names of `ArrayList` class. OP just use java-style naming for his methods

Comment: @JohnnyMopp The question, at least as it stands now, is not at all suitable for Code Review.

Comment: Actually this is C# code, I taged both since the question can be applied to both languages

Comment: @Mhd -- No, pick one.  Delete the other.

Comment: @Mhd your question is too abstract now. Because it's totally not clear what is purpose of class `B` and how do you use it's instances from `myList`. From code you provided I can say that you can use simple integer counter instead of list. Note that using `ArrayList` is a bad practice. Use `List<B`> instead

Comment: Impossible to answer which is better performance wise, it really depends on what is being done with them, and why.

Comment: Neither is good code; ArrayList is deprecated. Use `List<B>`.

Comment: In the first place the needs and the why of your question are not clear at all. Why using an ArrayList in the second solution while you can just change the instances of object directly? Why do you need the data of the previous reset while keeping the same instance of A?
Do you really need to reset an unknow number of objects and not just one or some? (In case, you know which objects is "resetting", try looking for an Observer design pattern.)

Comment: Since the codes do different things, the question about pwrformance is irrelevant... choose the code that do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Well, First of all - these codes are **not** equivalent - While in the first code you create a new instance of `B` every time you clear the `ArrayList`, in the second one you use the same instance of `B` all the time. This means that any changes made to this instace (assuming that `B` is not immutable) will be "canceled" every time you clear the `ArrayList` in the first code, but persist in the second one.

As to the question of which one is better "performance wise" - It usually depends on so many factors that it's almost always impossible to answer with complete confidence. In fact, it's so hard to answer this question correctly that [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) wrote an entire [blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) about it - and if it's hard for someone like him to answer - it's hard for anyone (unless your name is Jon Skeet :-))